# Scrapy - How to specify href inside link tag to get all pages and papers

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to obtain all the pages that contain the issues and, consequently, all the papers of this scientific journal (https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/phytochemistry/issues?page=1).

One of the problems is that when I try to fetch the url of the website on the scrapy shell to try to discover how to specify how to get these pages I get a 403 error.

The part that contains the href link that I want to get to the next page is (which is inside 'script'):

```
<link rel="next" href="https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/phytochemistry/issues?page=2" data-react-helmet="true">
```

The code I've written until now is pretty much bare and I wonder if I need to add a header to get rid of the 403 problem:

```
import scrapy


class PhytochemistrySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "phytochemistry"
    start_urls = ['https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/phytochemistry/issues?page=1']
```

Like mentioned above, I would like to scrape all the href links that contain the issues as well but I'd like to get some help in getting the pages and solving the 403 problem first.

How could I continue writing the code to get this done?

Thank you in advance and sorry for any obvious mistakes coming from a python and scrapy beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some user agents,

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get(url='https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/phytochemistry/issues?page=1')
<Response [403]>
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
>>> requests.get(url='https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/phytochemistry/issues?page=1', headers=headers)
<Response [200]>
```

apply the same in scrapy request as well.